# Bot conversation works in desktop Teams app but not supporrted in iOS

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a simple bot that has one command, and also responds to messages by echoing them back.
In desktop Teams, a command menu is displayed and the bot allows interaction.
In the iOS Teams app, there is no command menu and there is a message at the bottom of the chat tab saying "Conversation with this bot is not supported".
Is there a something specific that I need to do to allow this to work in iOS?

Comment: Can you please uninstall the app first and again reinstall and check?

Comment: Do you mean uninstall/reinstall the MS Teams iOS app from the device? Or the Teams App which implements the Bot?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT reinstalling the Teams iOS app seemed to work.... maybe because the bot originally did not have any conversation ability.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the existing app and reinstalling the Teams iOS app resolved the issue.